# Cannot print new line in StringBuilder

Tags: c#, for-loop, stringbuilder, generic-list

I'm trying to loop through a list and print each object on a new line however I can't seem to skip a line.

Below is the code:

```
private String displayProducts()
    {
        string header = "ID\tItem\tCategory\tPrice\tPrice\tStock";
        StringBuilder productsList = new StringBuilder(header);
        lstProducts_Load();
        for (int i = 0; i < products.Count(); i++)
        {
            productsList.AppendLine(products.ElementAt(i).Display());
            productsList.AppendLine();
        }
        return productsList.ToString();
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you "printing" the string ?

Comment: Im printing the list in another method. Ive called the displayProducts() in the code somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.Join(string separator, IEnumerable values)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for concatenating products with new line separator (it uses `StringBuilder` internally):

```
 header + String.Join(Environment.NewLine, products.Select(p => p.Display())
```

Consider also adding `\n` to the end of header, if you want first product to be on new line.

Comment: This seems to me to be problematic, creating what could possibly be a very large string and then appending it to a smaller string surely isn't a very good idea.

Comment: to be brutally honest, I have no idea whats happening with this code. Do I have to import something? All I'm getting is errors.

Comment: @EmmetMcLaughlin possibly you need to add `using System.Linq` directive for `Select` extension method to be available

Comment: @Ashigore : What should be the problem in the size difference? You don't add a large string to a smaller one. You create a third string out of the other two. Actually StringBuilder would need to to the same. A new potentially large string appended will force a recreating of the StringBuilders internal Buffer.

Answer (score 0):

How are you displaying it? With your code it displays correctly in a textbox or a label.

However a listbox is another story.  You're probably better off going with straight LINQ for that:

```
        listBox1.Items.Add("ID\tItem\tCategory\tPrice\tPrice\tStock");
        listBox1.Items.AddRange((from p in products
                                 from s in new string[] { p.Display(), "" }
                                 select s).ToArray());
```

This will add the Display output to the listbox and add an extra empty line between them.